# Is there a way to force std::condition_variable::notify_one in c++ to notify certain thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, condition-variable

I have multiple threads, created constantly in a loop, that access and modify single variable protected by mutex and synchronized by single condition_variable. While it works fine is there a way to chose which thread program will notify? For example most recently created one?

I was looking for solution on the internet but I wasn't able to find anything.

Comment: I can't think of a way with notify_one. Though I can thinks of a solution with a notify_all + a variable set to the value of the thread id that should continue. Then all waiting threads can in their wait predicate check if the value of the variable is the same as their own thread id. And only the thread for which this is true will continue.

Comment: It worries me that you say `created constantly in a loop`. That seems like a red flag in how to use threads.

Comment: A good rule of thumb in multi-threaded programming is; If something needs to be done, then it should not matter which thread does it. Condition variables were designed with that philosophy in mind. A thread that calls `notify_one` should neither know nor care which waiting thread will wake up and deal with whatever it was.

Answer (score 1):

Use two conditional variables, the first one for the first thread, the second one for the other threads. The first thread calls `notify_one()` of the second conditional variable.